# Find the image of the point by mapping $f$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I'm new to linear algebra and I don't understand how to find the image of the point by mapping. 
I have a matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}4&-2&0 \\ 2 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$$

the question if how can I find the image of the points$(3,2,3)^T$ and $(2,2,3)^T$.
at first i find the image of $A$, $(4, 2)^T$ but what should be the next step?

Comment: For any column vector $x\in\mathbb R^3$, the image of $x$ under $f$ is given by $f(x) = Ax$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did, but the image of  $(3,2,3)^t$ is found by matrix multiplication: $\begin{pmatrix}4&-2&0\\2&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}8\\4\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: so the image for the point $(2,2,3)^T$ is $(4,2)^T$, right?

Comment: Yes.  That's right.